# Why Dirac delta function is considered as wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, dirac-delta-distributions

I have read in my textbook that dirac delta function is regarded as wave function. But isn't it violating the condition required for a wave function ie .

It becomes infinite $ δ(x-x_0)$ at $x=x_0$ but wave function should be finite everywhere
How can this be explained??[image]

Book- Quantum physics by Hc verma, page 27, reprint 2018 edition.

Comment: A delta function is sometimes considered as a potential well or potential barrier $V(x)$ in the Schrodinger equation. Could that be what you read, rather than $\psi(x)$ being a delta function?

Comment: In the book they clearly state that the wavefunction is not realistic; however, it may be useful to conceptually understand how a fully 'localised' particle wavefunction would look like if you collapsed it to a definite position.

Comment: Who says the wavefunction has to be finite everywhere?

Comment: You are used to delocalized plane waves in coordinate space.  Consider such in momentum space and inspect their Fourier transform, representing them in coordinate space.

Comment: @Javier for most cases finiteness is required to maintain normalizability (you wouldn't accept $\psi(x) \propto \exp(kx)$ over all space, right?). The "delta function" is special in so far as it is really a *functional* that is defined in part by it's normalization. And that takes us into realms of analysis where I'm on very shaky ground, indeed.

Comment: @dmckee I understand that. My question was more of a rhetorical one; the point I would have made (if OP replies) is that a finiteness requirement is a bit naive: the value of a PDF at a point doesn't matter, what you want is square integrability.

Comment: @Javier With you on this: finiteness is a canard. As a pedagogical device, people routinely suspend normalizability (and square integrability of the wf). The OP has probably been told that the localized state $|x_0\rangle$ is only $\delta$-normalizable, and that its wf is $\langle x| x_0\rangle\propto \delta (x-x_0)$, not square integrable. Was introduced by Dirac in his classic book for that very purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delta function here can be thought of a position eigenstate, but as it is not square-integrable, it cannot be an actual wave function. Hence, "unrealistic". An actual, square-integrable wave function can be thought as being made of a superposition of dirac deltas, however:
$$
\psi(x) = \int \psi(x_0) \delta(x - x_0) dx_0.
$$

You can think of this as a superposition of dirac deltas at every possible $x_0$ along the real axis, with weight $\psi(x_0)dx_0$